# embed an external link in django app

Tags: django, django-templates

I added a link in myproject/templates/items/index.html like this

```
<a href="www.google.com">Search More</a>
```

My hope was that when a user clicks it, she would visit google.com. However, the result right now is this link is "myhost/items/www.google.com" instead of "www.google.com".

(I am modifying an existing app, and I have to admit I have not fully read django doc yet)

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with Django or templates, but is purely an HTML/browser issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Whenever you pass an external link to the `<a href=''>` tag, always use `http` .
So it will be like:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Search More</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

You forgot the protocol:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Search More</a>
```